# jQuery scroll on click to next href with same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three section component which all have the same class `.scrollLink` I want to click the text and have it scroll to the next instance of that class based on the anchor

I have an `onclick` function that when I click it is just remaining at the current class

HTML:

```
<a href="#panel1" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel2" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel3" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.scrollLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var toAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(toAnchor).offset().top - 100
  }, 'slow');
  console.log($(toAnchor));
});
```

click `.scrollLink` and go to next anchor (#) in section

Comment: Show your HTML too please.

Comment: add the HTML to the question so it is a complete, reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/f53mgncw/  you'll need to create an [mcve] version here as a snippet.

Comment: Worth noting: *"have it scroll to the next instance of that class"* - but your hrefs are all ID selectors, not class selectors, so not clear what you mean by "next instance of that class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<a href="#panel[n]>` are in sequential order in the DOM, you could create a reference collection of all `.scrollLink` and use it to determine which comes next in your `click` event handler.

**NOTE:** I'm short-circuiting the handler if the next one's index would exceed the number of elements in the object with a [guard clause](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html):

```
  if ( nextIndex == $scrollLinks.length ) { return; }
```

You could, as easily, set the index back to `0` to cycle through them from the beginning again.

**EDIT:** You mentioned going to the next anchor (presumably with the `scrollLink` class); I realize I'm unclear on whether you actually need the `href` attribute at all. Are there `id="panel1"`, `id="panel2"`, and `id="panel3"` elements on the page that weren't included in your sample HTML?

```js
var $scrollLinks = $('.scrollLink');

$('.scrollLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var nextIndex = $scrollLinks.index(this) + 1,
    toAnchor;

  if (nextIndex == $scrollLinks.length) {
    return;
  }

  toAnchor = $scrollLinks.eq(nextIndex);

  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: toAnchor.offset().top - 100 // toAnchor is already a jQuery object in this example; it needn't be wrapped in an additional `$()` here
  }, 'slow');
  console.log($(toAnchor));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#panel1" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel2" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel3" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
```